# Dexterity Container Type with Image Attribute

Tags: plone

environment: Plone 4.3.7, plone.app.contenttypes 1.1b5, eea.facetednavigation 8.7

I have a custom Dexterity Container type, [Monument](http://github.com/l34marr/tncr.content/blob/master/src/tncr/content/content.py#L8), that holds Image items only. My intention is to make `Monument containing Image items` behave just like `News Item with the Image field`. In case there are more than one Image items within Monument, the first one or a random one returned.

This way, I can display Monument items with their Image as thumbnails for eea.facetednavigation views.

FYI, there are 3 cases in eea.facetednavigation/views/[preview-item.pt](http://github.com/collective/eea.facetednavigation/blob/master/eea/facetednavigation/views/preview-item.pt) to show thumbnails:

```
is_namedimage python:getattr(getattr(context, 'image', None), 'getImageSize', None) is not None;
image_thumb exists:context/image_thumb;
image_tag python:getattr(context, 'tag', None)"
```

[image]

The example at [plone.app.discussion/interfaces.py](http://github.com/plone/plone.app.discussion/blob/master/plone/app/discussion/interfaces.py#L32) inspires me. So I try the following:

In `models/monument.xml`:

```
<schema>
...
 <field name="image"
  type="plone.namedfile.field.NamedBlobImage">
  <title i18n:translate="">Image</title>
  <readonly>True</readonly>
 </field>
...
</schema>
```

In `content.py`:

```
@implementer(IMonument)
class Monument(Container):
    """Container Subclass for Monument
    """

    @property
    def image(self):
        catalog = getToolByName(self, 'portal_catalog')
        path = '/'.join(self.getPhysicalPath())
        brain = catalog(path={"query": path}, portal_type=['Image'])
        obj = brain[0].getObject()
        return obj.image
```

But, it seems Monument item does not get `image` attribute accordingly. Am I moving toward the right direction? Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: For an out-of-the-box solution you can try eea.depiction add-on http://eea.github.io/docs/eea.depiction/index.html. But be aware that once installed, it will provide thumbnails for all of your content types.

Comment: Thanks @avoinea that's inspiring. It also makes sense providing such a generic system for creating thumbnails. Hopefully there will be Dexterity support soon. https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/AshRjMgJmMYTdgNW0rPOltMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the LeadImageBehavior for your Monument-Foldertype? In profiles/default/types/monument.xml add this if you need a image field.
Then you can register IObjectModifiedEvent for Monument and manipulate the imagefield in the event.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="Monument" meta_type="Dexterity FTI">
  <property name="behaviors" purge="False">
    <element value="plone.app.contenttypes.behaviors.leadimage.ILeadImage"/>
  </property>
</object>
```